# Query to find team with highest number of fans?

Tags: mysql, function

i am attempting to create a MySQL function that will return one single entity with the highest amount of fans. Just wondering my logic is right. I've tried multiple different versions of this select and feel as though i'm near the solution now. I am no longer receiving any errors, what i get when i call it is:

```
select Popular_team() LIMIT 0, 1000 OK  0.00054 sec
```

here is my select statement:

```
SELECT TeamName INTO team_var
FROM team
WHERE (select max(count(TeamId)) FROM fan GROUP BY TeamId);
```

any inputs would be appreciated,
Thank-You.

Comment: Is there really a need to make this a function? That seems overly specific.

Comment: No could easily be preformed without one. We're currently learning procedures/functions for MySQL so that involves us creating tons of useless code, lol.

Comment: Ah, so it's an academic thing. That's fine. It's just that stored procedures and functions are usually reserved for things that are difficult if not impractical to do in actual queries, like GIS extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT TeamNameINTO team_var FROM team WHERE TeamId in (SELECT TeamId
                    FROM team
                    GROUP BY TeamId
                    ORDER BY COUNT(*))
```

Comment: Some (small) explanation about why, what or how this code works, will qualify as a better answer and makes your post more usefully. Please consider doing so.

Comment: Thank-you. Didn't even think about order by count. Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `group by`, `order by`, and `limit`:

```
SELECT team_var := (SELECT TeamName
                    FROM team
                    GROUP BY TeamName
                    ORDER BY COUNT(*)
                    LIMIT 1
                   );
```

You cannot nest aggregation functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with sub-queries but it's pretty choppy:

```
SELECT sub2.TeamName
FROM
(SELECT MAX(cnt) AS mx
 FROM
 (SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
  FROM team
  GROUP BY TeamName)) sub1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT TeamName, COUNT(*) AS cnt
 FROM team
 GROUP BY TeamName) sub2
ON sub1.mx = sub2.cnt
```

Answer (score 0):

Especially for web stuff, and you may get to millions of rows, this is an exception of denormalization I would use a separate column for the total fans and have an index on that on your team table. Then query from that directly.  Now, how to keep that updated?  Using a trigger.  Every time someone clicks on whatever means and adds a record to the "fan" table for a given team, you just update the team tables fanCount column.  This way you never have to worry about re-aggregating every time to get your results.  The table has its total already accounted for and has an index.

So, if I had a table

```
Teams
------
TeamID,  TeamName, FanCount

Fans
FanID, TeamID
```

Now, an insert trigger for the Fans table.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER AddedFanRecord
AFTER INSERT ON Fans FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    Update Teams
        set FanCount = FanCount +1
        where
            TeamID = NEW.TeamID;

END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

So, anyone at any time can add themselves as a fan of a given team.  Without you having to do anything else, the FanCount column is updated.  Now, just run your query directly on you very small team table.  (Ex: to get the 5 top teams by number of fans)

```
Select * from Teams
   order by FanCount DESC
   limit 5
```

You could use a correlated update command to pre-populate your count base on existing records already in the system, such as

```
update Teams
   JOIN ( select TeamID, count(*) numFans
             from Fans
             group by TeamID ) PreQuery
   on Teams.TeamID = PreQuery.TeamID
   set FanCount = PreQuery.NumFans
```

So now you can start with your table already synchronized with proper starting totals and it keeps getting updated for all fans.  You might need to do another trigger to reduce the count in such case as someone deletes their entry for being a fan of a particular team.

Queries by themselves are pretty simple, but having a more scalable answer for longer term might be a better option for you.